# Can you conjecture what functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous when considered as maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R_\mathcal{l}}$?

Tags: general-topology

The complete question is from Mukres's *Topology*.

(a) Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is "continuous from the right" that is 
$$\lim_{x \to a^{+}} f(x) = f(a),$$
for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is continuous when considered as a function from $\mathbb{R_\mathcal {l}}$ to $ \mathbb{R}$.

(b) Can you conjecture what functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous when considered as maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R_\mathcal {l}}$? As maps from $\mathbb{R_\mathcal {l}}$ to $\mathbb{R_\mathcal {l}}$?

NOTE:$\mathbb{R_\mathcal {l}}$ is the topology generated by the basis $\{[a,b)|a,b\in R\}$.

It is easy to prove the first part of the question. But I have no idea about how to figure out the second part of the question. Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please define $\mathbb R_l$.

Comment: @Rasmus:$\mathbb{R_\mathcal{l}}$ is the topology generated by the basis {$[a, b) |a, b\in \mathbb{R}$}.

Comment: First observation: This topology is finer than the usual one. Can you guess a function which is continuous as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ but not as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_l$? In fact, it is quite hard for a function to be continuous from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R_l$.

Comment: You might want to put the definition of $\mathbb R_l$ into the question so that others can find it more easily.

Comment: Definitely not, because any set that is open in $\mathbb{R}$ is definitely open in $\mathbb{R_\mathcal{l}}$. But I could not find out a function which is not continuous as a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ but not as a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R_\mathcal{l}}$.

Comment: Look at the function $x\mapsto x$.

Comment: Yeah, the identity function is a good example, but is there a more precise and general statement?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1401/discussion-between-jichao-and-rasmus)

Comment: Does not matter. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint (for $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_\ell$): The continuous image of a connected set is connected. What are the connected components of $\mathbb{R}_\ell$?

Comment: I haven't learnt connectivity before.Anyway, the excercise say we'd return to this question after we have learnt it. So thanks for your hint.

Comment: That's a nice idea!

Comment: @Jichao: If you know that the only open and closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$, then this nice argument can be used without referring to connectedness. Note that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}_l$ and $\epsilon>0$ the sets $[x,x+\epsilon)$ are open and closed in $\mathbb{R}_l$. Then so are the sets $f^{-1}[x,x+\epsilon)$ because $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @LostInMath: Why for any $x \in \mathbb{R_\mathcal{l}}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ the sets $[x, x + \epsilon)$ are open and closed in $\mathbb{R_\mathcal{l}}$.

Comment: @Jichao: They are open since they are elements of the generating basis of $\mathbb{R}_l$. They are closed since the complements are open: $\mathbb{R}_l\setminus[x,x+\epsilon)=\bigcup_{y<x}[y,x)\cup\bigcup_{y>x+\epsilon}[x+\epsilon,y)$ is a union of open sets, hence open.

Comment: @LostInMath: Thanks for your detailed explaination.

Answer (score 5):

To get you started on $f:\mathbb{R}_\ell \to \mathbb{R}_\ell$:

If $f$ is continuous as a function from $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ to $\mathbb{R}_\ell$, then it must be continuous as a function from $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ to $\mathbb{R}$, since every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is also open in $\mathbb{R}_\ell$. Thus, as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ it must be continuous from the right. However, this isn’t enough: $f(x)=-x$ is continuous as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but it’s not continuous as a function from $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ to $\mathbb{R}_\ell$. Why? If you can see what keeps this function from being continuous from $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ to $\mathbb{R}_\ell$, you’ve a good chance of working out exactly which functions from $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ to $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ are continuous.